# Javascript : Store data in variables by for loop

Tags: javascript

I am having some random JSON data at the moment, therefore I cannot using standrad way to do it, cannot do it one by one.

For example if i am going to store specific data as array i will do something like below

```
var tester = []; // store their names within a local array

for(var k = 0; i < data.result.length; i++){ //maybe 6

   for(var i = 0; i < data.result.data.length; i++){ //maybe 30 times in total

       tester.push(data.result[k].data[i].someNames);
    }

}
```

But since I cannot predict how many set of data i have i can't really do something like

```
 var tester = []; 
 var tester2 = []; 
 var tester3 = []; 
 var tester4 = []; 

   for(var i = 0; i < data.result.data.length; i++){ //maybe 30 times in total

       tester.push(data.result[0].data[i].someNames);
        tester2.push(data.result[1].data[i].someNames);
        tester3.push(data.result[2].data[i].someNames);
        tester4.push(data.result[3].data[i].someNames);


       }
```

if there' any better way which using for loop to store these data?

Comment: maybe use a while loop that runs until you are out of data?

Comment: The double `for` loops are your best bet. Also, `for(var i = 0; i < data.result.data.length; i++)` Should be changed to: `for(var i = 0; i < data.result[k].data.length; i++)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make `tester` a 2-dimensional array and use nested loops.

```
var tester = [];

for (var i = 0; i < data.result.length; i++) {
    var curTester = [];
    var result = data.result[i];
    for (var j = 0; j < result.data.length; j++) {
        curTester.push(result.data[j].someNames);
    }
    tester.push(curTester);
}
```

Some general principles:

1. Any time you find yourself defining variables with numeric suffixes, they should probably be an array.
2. When you don't know how many of something you're going to have, put them in an array.